# 4 days spent openCV won't install

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I have tried and exhausted almost every tact and work through on the internet to install the openCV for android in my eclipse which has an updated ADT and also CDT installed in it, I tried deleting the .settings folder before importing the library and the examples.

Im including the android version 4.0.3 into the example builds but I don't think this is any problem.

here is the summary of what errors I receive (many of the following errors are shown duplicated(at various lines) in the error console im just listing them once!)

```
  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  OpenCVEngineInterface cannot be resolved  AsyncServiceHelper.java /OpenCV Library - 
  2.4.6/src/org/opencv/android  line 160    Java Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  OpenCVEngineInterface cannot be resolved to a type    AsyncServiceHelper.java 
 /OpenCV Library - 2.4.6/src/org/opencv/android line 160    Java Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  R cannot be resolved to a variable    CameraBridgeViewBase.java   /OpenCV 
  Library - 2.4.6/src/org/opencv/android    line 72 Java Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
     'C:\Work\OpenCV4Android\OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library -
  2.4.6.jar'    OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle       Build path  Build Path
   Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  The import org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface cannot be resolved
AsyncServiceHelper.java /OpenCV Library - 2.4.6/src/org/opencv/android  line 7  
  Java Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  The import org.opencv.R cannot be resolved    CameraBridgeViewBase.java   
  /OpenCV Library - 2.4.6/src/org/opencv/android    line 5  Java Problem

  Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
  Unable to resolve target 'android-11' OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle   
Unknown Android Target Problem
```

right now im not caring about the 7 warnings posed by the IDE!

UPDATE!

As soon as I downloaded the Android 3.0 (The level 11) all the errors are gone all! but then I'm developing not for the tablets honeycomb devices I'm developing for a jelly bean 4.1.2 mobile phone!, What to do?

Comment: please help me! I have many things correct in my setup like compliance level 1.6 selected but still errors are there!

Comment: How can we help you if you show your errors but don't show what/when/where they are arise, and what you have and what you to do?

Comment: can you guide me in fresh installation for openCV for eclipse Android its getting all complicated and I don;t know what to look for?

Comment: As soon as I downloaded the Android 3.0 (The level 11) all the errors are gone all! but then I'm developing not for the tablets honeycomb devices I'm developing for a jelly bean 4.1.2 mobile phone!, What to do?

Comment: everthings SOLVED, Thanks BUT wait.....No Thanks!

Comment: What was your solution? I have same problem now

Comment: I installed it at the same place again where My android-sdks etc were residing